# Создание ets-таблицы с защищенными данными

Tags: erlang

В проекте ppool-1.0 из книги Фреда Хеберта "Изучай Erlang..." появилась
необходимость создать ets-таблицу с защищенными данными. Для этого в файл
ppool.erl был добавлен следующий код
    table(Name, Tabl) ->
        ppool_serv:table(Name, Tabl).
в файл ppool_serv.erl
    table(Name, Tabl) ->
        gen_server:call(Name, {table, Tabl}).
...
    handle_call({table, Tabl}, _From, S = #state{limit=N, sup=Sup, refs=R}) ->
    Args = ets:new(Tabl, [named_table, public, {heir, self(), undefined}]), % line 62
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_child(Sup, Args),
    Ref = erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
    {reply, {ok,Pid}, S#state{limit=N-1, refs=gb_sets:add(Ref,R)}};
После компиляции и запуска, появляется ошибка
    1> application:start(ppool).
    ok
    2> ppool:start_pool(table, 0,{ppool_table, start_link, []}).
    {ok,<0.41.0>}
    3> ppool:table(table, [order]).

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 9-Nov-2015::16:48:01 ===  
** Generic server table terminating   
** Last message in was {table,[order]}  
** When Server state == {state,0,<0.43.0>,{0,nil},{[],[]}}  
** Reason for termination ==   
** {badarg,[{ets,new,
                 [[order],[named_table,public,{heir,<0.42.0>,undefined}]],  
                 []},  
            {ppool_serv,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/ppool_serv.erl"},{line,62}]},  
            {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,  
                        [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},  
            {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}  
** exception exit: {{badarg,  
                        [{ets,new,  
                             [[order],  
                              [named_table,public,{heir,<0.42.0>,undefined}]],  
                             []},  
                         {ppool_serv,handle_call,3,  
                             [{file,"src/ppool_serv.erl"},{line,62}]},  
                         {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,  
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},  
                         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,  
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},  
                         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,  
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]},  
                    {gen_server,call,[table,{table,[order]}]}}  
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 204)
```

В чем может быть причина? Опции указаны правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключалась в преждевременном создании ets таблицы, то есть это необходимо делать уровнем ниже, в worker'е.